# Removing rows with certain year (date)

Tags: r, date, rows

My dataset contains two columns:

1. dates with `Date` class, so not a string `yyyy-mm-dd`;
2. a certain count.

I want to remove all rows with the year 2017.

`df$date > "2016-12-31"` (so using a > sign) keeps giving the warning

> "Error in date > "2016-12-31" : 
>     comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types"

in all the many, many many ways I've tried it. It seems that simply "<" can't be used, even though these are most of the solutions online. Any idea how to remove rows with a certain year in another way?

Comment: Stefanie, please provide `dput(head(df$date))`

Answer (score 5):

Use `format()`:

```
df <- df[format(df$date,'%Y') != "2017", ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If `df$date` is with class `Date` it should work. See the example:

```
> df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(runif(10, -200, 200), origin = Sys.Date()))
> df
         date
1  2017-03-02
2  2017-05-09
3  2016-09-08
4  2016-10-27
5  2016-12-03
6  2016-07-05
7  2017-02-21
8  2017-05-24
9  2016-07-04
10 2016-09-06
> 
> df$date > "2016-12-31"
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```